# Problem to include EPS file with file name containing "#"

Tags: graphics, errors, eps

I have problem including EPS in LaTeX document. I am using `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` workflow to compile LaTeX document file. Error is thrown as

> Illegal parameter number in definition

The EPS file is generated by OriginPro7.5 by default ouput setting. It can be viewed in evince in Ubuntu. So is there any requirement for an eps file to be successfully included in LaTeX?

EDIT: To be more specific, below is the LaTeX snippet,

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{figures/A.eps}
\end{figure}
```

Following error is thrown,

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempb.
<to be read again>
1.6 ...idth=4.5cm]{figures/A.eps}
```

But when I replace `A.eps` with `B.eps`, the system works fine, which makes me believe it's a problem of the EPS file.

EDIT2: The real file name contains special character `#`, which is the cause of this problem. After removing `#` from the file name, problem solved.

Comment: you have a macro or environment definition with a defined number of parameters, eg [2], but you are using eg #3 as a parameter in the code part, which is not possible. However, it has _nothing_ to do with the eps image.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I think it has to do with eps file. I actually replace the current eps with another one. Then it works well. Btw, can you be more specific about which macro?

Comment: What's the name of the file causing the error?

Comment: real file name is `rand_#_sample0.5_1.eps`..PS: when I remove # from the file name, it works... thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `\includegraphics` does its work, it stores the file name in a macro, so a name such as `rand_#_sample0.5_1.eps` will produce the illegal

```
\def\@tempb{rand_#_sample0.5_1.eps}
```

So no `#` is allowed in a file name.

Answer (score 4):

arguably that's a bug in latex, please submit a bug report, latex latexbug and follow the instructions to submit a bug in category graphics

Meanwhile, if renaming the file is inconvenient, I believe this should work

```
\edef\f{rand_\string#_sample0.5_1.eps}
\includegraphics[...]{\f}
```

Comment: With clarification from the OP about the file name containing `#`, I don't think this is a LaTeX bug.

Comment: well that's what I meant, I don't think we say anywhere that `#` isn't allowed and it could be made safe I assume, but perhaps it isn't worth it { couldn't be automatically made safe for instance.

Comment: If one wants that `\includegraphics` can be an argument to another command, I guess it's quite difficult to allow `#` in a name; unless the definition that causes the error can be avoided. However, +1 for the workaround.

Comment: I wouldn't change catcodes (the source of most problems of using things in arguments) but the filename _could_ be sanitised with `\meaning ` or the e-tex re-scanning, at the cost of extra processing just for this edge case of weird names.

Comment: Well, weirdness is in the eye of the beholder :-) Strictly speaking, it should be up to the file system to decide if a file name is valid or not.

Comment: @daniel, Well, there are some constraints if we choose to use a system with filename handling dating from the 1980's :-) but here the system can handle the character it's just a question of user expectations. I think no one would be surprised if you had to escape `\ ` or `{ ` in some way as they are obviously special to TeX, `# ` is similarly special but the user expectation may be different.

Comment: True, I wasn't aware of that it is possible to escape `#` in this situation. This should be mentioned to the OP.